# Move UILabel based on scrollview postion

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have a titleLabel inside my headerView (the image view) which changes its size based on the scroll view scrolling. I'm trying to move the titlelabel also based on the position of the scroll view as it resizes to about the same size as a navigation bar I'm trying to move the label to a position that reflects a navigation title. This is how I'm trying to do it currently.

```
    self.view.addSubview(self.imageView)
    self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true

    self.imageHeightConstraint = self.imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400)
    self.imageHeightConstraint.isActive = true

    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
    scrollView.anchor(top: imageView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: -10, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -100)
```

**ScrollViewDidScroll**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let y = 100 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y - 100)
    let height = max(y, 100)
    self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = height

    self.eventTitleLabel.center.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y 
}
```

Comment: Is your `imageView` changing size as desired? If not, that's the first thing to fix. If yes, then what is not working? You haven't shown anything related to your `titleLabel`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change not just Y value , you need to change all frame like this

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let y = 100 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y - 100)
    let height = max(y, 100)
    self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = height

    //self.eventTitleLabel.center.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y 
    self.eventTitleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y , width: label.frame.width, height: label.frame.height)

}
```

here , X and Y manage with your scrollview as your position you want.

Comment: This code isn't moving my label into the imageView. It doesn't seem to be doing anything for me

Comment: @CodyHost  may be your constraints issue occurring  , you need to update or replace your all set constraints.